# Get SubItem value when double-clicking on Item in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, subitem

I have a listview with 2 columns, and when the I double click on an item, i need to display the value of its corresponding sub item in a TextBox control. How can I do this?

I searched Google, but it didn't return anything helpful, probably because I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

Thank you

Comment: It can't be THAT hard... Windows does it all the time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MSDN links you'll want to read are [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx) and [ListViewSubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx).
You access the subitems of your list view item through the `ListViewItem.SubItems` property
Most important thing to remember is that the first sub-item refers to the owner list view item so to access the actual sub-items you need to index starting at 1. This will return you a `ListViewSubItem` object and you can get it's text string by calling `ListViewSubItem.Text`.

i.e
`SubItems[0]` gives you the 'parent' list view item
`SubItems[1]` gives you the first sub-item etc

Quick, nasty code snippet

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      ListView.SelectedIndexCollection sel = listView1.SelectedIndices;

      if (sel.Count == 1)
      {
          ListViewItem selItem = listView1.Items[sel[0]];
          textBox1.Text = selItem.SubItems[1].Text;
      }
}
```

Hope that helps